# FaceTime number has space

Tags: iphone, facetime

I am getting this strange behavior when making a Facetime call. The number is just a test number`(123-456-7890)` but the way it reads in Facetime is `+12 3 456 7890`

Is there a way to change that in code or am I stuck with putting a leading 1 on every number?

The error I recieve on the phone is:

```
FaceTime Failed
+12 3 456 7890 is not aviailable for FaceTime
```

I understand it wont work but the space will mess the real numbers later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the country code to the number 1-123-456-7890

Comment: Seems to be the only solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a test number that doesn't start with 1 -- for instance, 555-555-5555 is valid (and meaningless). NANP (US/Canada) phone numbers never start with 1, so the leading 1 is being treated as part of a country calling code.

Comment: I have also tried my phone number as a test but it still fills the first digit as the long distance number.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove all space in the string before making facetime call.
example: facetime://+1234567890